# Report Lab - raise ValueError('paraparser: syntax error: %s' % message) ValueError: (u"paraparser: syntax error: invalid attribute name alt attrMap

Tags: python, reportlab

Using Reportlab to generate pdfs and all has been going well. Ran into an issue that throws the following error...

```
raise ValueError('paraparser: syntax error: %s' % message)
ValueError: (u"paraparser: syntax error: invalid attribute name alt attrMap=['height', 'src', 'valign', 'width']", '\nparagraph text u\'<para><p><strong>
```

It seems this is being caused by an a character that ReportLab doesn't like, as I can get around it using "escape" but that results in the paragraph ignoring formatting such as `<P>` and `<strong>`

Is there a quick way to identify the character in question? Or perhaps another way to work around this issue?

```
def getDescription(eventid):

    res = tq.get("api/events/%s/" % eventid)
    ed = res['data']['description']

    if not ed:
        logger.debug("No description exists for event %s. Skipping this section." % eventid)
        return()
    else:   
        formattedDesc = ed.replace('\n', '<br/>')
        logger.debug("Description of event is \n %s" % formattedDesc)
        #Story.append(Paragraph(escape(formattedDesc), styles["TQ-Description"]))
        #Changed to the following to prevent an error thrown by XX reports. Need to figure out why.
        Story.append(Paragraph(escape(formattedDesc), styles["TQ-Description"]))
```

Comment: What makes you think this is caused by a specific character? The error tells you it is caused by an invalid attribute name. You need to show the actual code you are using that triggers this error.

Comment: My apologies, and thanks for looking. If not a character, perhaps something in the text is getting misconstrued as an attribute. I say this because things have been working fine until I used a new source to pull the data from. (This source is heavily formatted)
Updates with actual code snip....